# .net max class size

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-construction

Is there a limitation (perhaps a compiler limitation) on the size of a class in ASP.NET 3.5?

I have a single class file that is going to keep growing and could become quite large (easily 100k lines of code, or 10k members).

I simply need to know if there is a limit on lines of code, or raw file size, or quantity of members in a single class.

Please do not ask why I'm doing something that sounds both stupid and crazy; I'm well aware of the consequences of such an approach.

Comment: "100k lines of code" You should really start learning [OOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460654.aspx).

Comment: I'm going to try really hard not to ask said question, but you could at least start working with the `partial` keyword if the code absolutely *has to be* in one class.

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb here and just say `You're doing it wrong`

Comment: I guess since you are on this path you are welcome to post an answer of the limit if you come across one (*since you are not asking for any alternatives*).

Comment: @TimSchmelter and vanneto, i can immage legittimate scenario in which such situation could happen.
What if he use that class as LUT container?
I came across that post for that reason (i have a big LUT and i'm not sure if it can be statically stored in the binary or if i should load it from a file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely not, there is not a max size of a class.

Comment: Well there is going to be an Operating System limitation on the file size

Comment: Theoretically true. Practically, with a `4GB` file size UTF-8 encoded with each line being ~100 bytes you could still have `~42 000 000` lines in that file. Which is wrong. :P

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I had a file with 165k lines of code (~6MB) that I had generated with a tool of mine (it was meant to load some test data).

On Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) I received a System.AccessViolationException when I attempted to use the type in the file.

So it would seem there is indeed some limit.

I should mention this was using .NET Core 2.0