# Is there a maximum number of entities or associations in LINQ-to-SQL?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql

I have problems with drag and dropping tables in the LINQ-to-SQL designer. And the associations (relations between the tables) are not configured automatically in the designer source. The file reached a number of 30.000 lines.

Is there a maximum number of entities or associations in LINQ-to-SQL?

Comment: Have you created your relations in the DB?

Comment: Well, since designer class is just another `.cs` file (or xml file depends on designer) there are [no limits](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14437389/1849444) to it. The only limit could be is your local system perfomance.

Comment: I have a SQL Server 2012. The relations are created in the database. (FK) Each table has a PK that consists of one attribute named:[tablename + Id].